# unable to get javascript code perfected for an input type=range to effect setInterval time

Tags: javascript, input, html5-canvas, label

I am a newbie, and find myself banging my head over where I have failed in creating the effect of adjusting the 'time' inside the setInterval (function, t). The setInterval works great as a stand alone with ability to adjust time manually, but I wanted to attach a range slider to adjust the time dynamically.

The code I have is:

```js
var ctx, v, c;

var text='All Male';

var speed = 500;




var angle = 0;


window.onload = init;


function init (){
  
  
  c = document.querySelector('#c');
  
  ctx=c.getContext('2d');
  
  drawShapes();
  drawRotatingText();
  
  
  
  
   setInterval("drawRotatingText()",speed);
   
   
   // Here is what what does not work
   
   speedV = document.querySelector('#speedV'); 
 
document.getElementById('speed').addEventListener('change', changeSpeed);

}

function changeSpeed(event) {

 
  
speed = parseInt(event.this.value);}
```

```html
 <input id="speed" min="125" max="500" value="500" step="any" oninput="changeSpeed(event);" type="range"><output id="speedV"></output>
    <label for="speed">Text Speed</label> 
 
    <canvas id="c" class="canv" width="600" height="400">Your browerse does not support the canvas tag</canvas>
```

Thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it's pointless to make the `milliseconds` parameter of the `setInterval()` function a variable as it will only be called **once** in your code as part of the `init()` function. Changing the `speed` variable to something different later on won't change the interval in any way.

Beside this I guess you might be thinking that the speed variable is tied to the interval in some way, well that's not the case. As soon as `setInterval(drawRotatingText, speed);` is executed, the actual value of speed (at the time of execution) gets passed - not the variable itself.

Now I must say the whole thing is not the best conceptually but if we want to go that route, a simple fix is replacing `setInterval` by `setTimeout`. Unlike setInterval, it's callback function will just be called once **but** you can retrigger it right inside this callback handler and use the current value of speed as determined by the range slider.

Here's an example roughly based on your code (just hit 'Run code snippet'):

```js
var ctx, v, c;
var text = 'All Male';
var speed = 500;
var interval;
var xPos = 0;

function drawText() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.fillText(text, xPos, 55);
  if (xPos + 1 > c.width) {
    xPos = 0;
  } else {
    xPos++;
  }

  interval = setTimeout(drawText, speed);
}

function init() {
  c = document.querySelector('#c');
  ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = "30px Verdana";

  document.getElementById('speed').addEventListener('input', changeSpeed);
  interval = setTimeout(drawText, speed);
}

function changeSpeed(event) {
  speed = parseInt(event.target.value);
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<canvas id="c" class="canv" width="300" height="100" style="background-color:grey;">Your browerse does not support the canvas tag</canvas><br>
<input id="speed" min="25" max="500" value="500" step="any" type="range">
<label for="speed">Text Speed</label>
```

Comment: the text is spinning in a circle.function drawRotatingText ( x,y ) {
   ctx. clearRect(0, 0, 150, 110); 
  ctx. translate(x,y);
  ctx .rotate(Math.PI / 3);   
  ctx. translate(-40, -95); // the y integer pulls the text apart as it increases.
    ctx. fillText(text, 0,0,85,90);
  
  ctx.restore();
  
}  

If I wanted to control movement within a horizontal only box or to bounce back and forth sure. Hence, I scratch my head

Comment: Uhm - I'm not sure I understand what you say. The above is a generic solution no matter what you draw on the canvas as we merely alter the speed of the update. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: It solved my headache. Thank you very much.  I didn't realize i needed a setTimeout. Again, thank you.

Comment: No problem darryl - glad I could help! =)